# Installing TL-WN823N on raspberry pi 2B

Tags: raspbian, wifi, kernel

I bought a Wi-Fi adapter to use on my Pi 2. I've already installed the driver rtl8192eu, (found on github). but, when I run `lsusb`, the Pi cant recognize the Wi-Fi adapter, it just shows  me:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109
```

when I run `lsmod`, I get this:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   10340  2 
bluetooth             326105  5 bnep
binfmt_misc             6388  1 
cfg80211              428871  0 
rfkill                 16037  4 cfg80211,bluetooth
8192eu                908687  0 
joydev                  9024  0 
evdev                  11396  6 
snd_bcm2835            20447  1 
snd_pcm                75762  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              19288  1 snd_pcm
snd                    51908  5 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
bcm2835_wdt             3225  0 
bcm2835_gpiomem         2976  0 
uio_pdrv_genirq         3164  0 
uio                     8000  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                 5859  0 
fuse                   84037  3 
ipv6                  347620  72
```

when I run `iwconfig`, I get this:

```
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I'm using kernel version 4.4.50-v7+ and I would prefer not to upgrade it for a newer version.

can anyone explain what is happening and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i do lsusb, rpi cant recognize the wifi adapter
>
> `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109`

That output is fine.  That's how the device identifies itself.  I believe the string often shown (e.g., `Acme 0.1 wifi adapter`) is one the kernel gets from somewhere, but not necessarily an actual driver because it will identify devices with no driver too.  Perhaps it comes from the device -- in any case it is not important.

> when i do iwconfig, i get this
>
> `wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"`

If the driver works well enough for that, *most likely* it will work in general.  If the driver did not work, the interface would not be listed at all.

> can anyone explain what is happening and how to solve this?

None of this amounts to a problem.

Comment: You are right, goldilocks.
At this time, the driver was working fine, I just needed to configure my wlan. i did this procedure https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md and now I`m using Wi-fi nicely. thanks for your help.